# Is there a list attribute of 'start' in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

This is a problem from leetcode 56. The problem is: 'Given a collection of intervals, merge all overlapping intervals.'

I copied other's successful solution but when I run it it shows error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'start'

Why???

```
class Solution(object):
    def merge(self, intervals):
        """
        :type intervals: List[Interval]
        :rtype: List[Interval]
        """
        if len(intervals) == 0: return []
        intervals = sorted(intervals, key = lambda x: x.start)
        res = [intervals[0]]
        for n in intervals[1:]:
            if n.start <= res[-1].end: res[-1].end = max(n.end, res[-1].end)
            else: res.append(n)
        return res
```

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'start'
Line 8 in <lambda> (Solution.py)
Line 8 in merge (Solution.py)
Line 32 in main (Solution.py)
Line 40 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: It looks like you're passing in a 2D list of Intervals. It expects a plain list of Intervals.

Comment: test example:Input: [[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
Output: [[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
Explanation: Since intervals [1,3] and [2,6] overlaps, merge them into [1,6].

Comment: `Interval` appears to be an actual class, not simply a list of two items. Your input is in the incorrect format.

Comment: I can't find such a class by Googling, but it has to be a class with `start` and `end` attributes. To answer your question, no, lists don't have those attributes. Did they include the class to be used in the challenge?

Comment: no they didn't. I understand your point. But still can't figure out why this copied solution is so up-voted

Comment: Hey Hua Zhao,
They have included a class that defines the start and end in the leet code problem. It is commented out purposefully.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the input arguments is of type List of Lists, rather than List of Intervals. The below code works for me.

```
    def merge(self, intervals):
        """
        :type intervals: List[Interval]
        :rtype: List[Interval]
        """  
        if intervals is None:
            return None

        intervals.sort(key= lambda x: x[0])
        merged = []
        for interval in intervals:
            if len(merged) == 0 or interval[0] > merged[-1][1]:
                merged.append(interval)
            else:
                merged[-1][1] = max(interval[1], merged[-1][1])  

        return merged
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:
just replace `i.start ~ i[0]` and `i.end ~ i[1]`

Comment: Probably you could be right, but without an explanation of your code and how it solves the OP problem your answer is a low quality one.